# How to check in linux an R package developed in Windows

Tags: r, linux, windows, package

I've some problems submitting an R package to CRAN. The submission don't pass the check for linux systems. An error is generating with this log:

> check_dm(MEDITS::TA,wd,suffix)   Warning in file.create(Errors) :
> cannot create file '/tmp/Rtmpsn6oQ6/working_dir/RtmpptBi2J/Logfiles/Logfile_2020-03-05_time_h17m44s55.dat',
> reason 'No such file or directory'   Warning in file(file,
> ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
> cannot open file '/tmp/Rtmpsn6oQ6/working_dir/RtmpptBi2J/Logfiles/Logfile_2020-03-05_time_h17m44s55.dat':
> No such file or directory   Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a",
> "w")) :
> cannot open the connection   Calls: check_dm -> write -> cat -> file   Execution halted

This error is not generated in Windows, where the package passes without any error or warning. It seems like Linux generates a nested temporary directory in the previous defined.

There is a way to test on either a local or a remote machine the package on a Linux system without resubmitting it to the CRAN every times?
Anybody can help me solving this problem?

Comment: You can check with R-hub, take a look at the `rhub` package.

Comment: thank you, I will check it.